# how come a virual address is only 48 bits rather than 64 bits?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, process, virtual-memory

I was reading a book which talks about virtual memory:

Intel Core i7 supports a 48-bit (256 TB) virtual address space and a 52-bit (4 PB) physical address space
[image]

below is my question

Q1-since we mostly use 64 bits machine, how come the virual address is only 48 bits? shouldn't it be 64 bits virual memory as well?

Q2-How come the address space of physical memory(52 bits) is greater than virtual memory's(48 bits), shouldn't it be that virtual memory's address space should be greater than physical memory's?

Q3-my understanding is that: all page tables stored in kernel memory which is invisible to user, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Multiply posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63975447/340790 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No 64-bit processor that I know of fully supports 64-bit addresses. The registers are 64 bits wide, and 8 bytes are used for storing a pointer, but the pointer values are typically constrained to effective 48 bits by forcing the most significant bits to be all zeroes or all ones.

The reason for this is that a full 64-bit address space is not (yet) needed, and it would be a waste of silicon to support something that is not needed. Supporting the full 64-bit address space would complicate the virtual to physical mapping for no good.

Exponential growth in memory address space means adding a constant number of address bits in a given time, not doubling the number of bits. So, if one evolutionary step was going from 16 address bits to 32 bits, then the next step up from 32 bits is 32+16 = 48 bits, not 64 bits. Expanding the address registers to 64 bits makes sense, because 48 bits would be somewhat awkward to handle, and provides an architecture that is ready for "real" 64-bit addresses when the time for them has come.

Q2: why not? A bigger physical address address space enables you to have multiple processes each with a virtual address space up to the 2^48 limit. Most 32-bit x86 processors in the last decade (two decades?) have supported the Physical Address Extension (PAE), which supports 64 GB physical memory, although the virtual address space is limited to 4 GB as defined by the original 80386 instruction set architecture.

Q3: yes, the page tables are managed by the kernel, and are stored in kernel memory.